# How to get multiple column value from database into a list using LINQ query

Tags: sqlite, linq, xamarin.forms

I would like to get `FullName, Email`column values using LINQ query in c# to a list and then get these values, but it giving below error;
`Cannot implicity convert type Systems.Collections.Generic.List<<anoynymous type: string FullName>>`

```
List <PlayerDetails> details = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(x => x.Email == emailTextVal).Select(p => new { p.FullName }) select x).ToList();
  SoccerAvailability soccerAvailability = new SoccerAvailability();
  soccerAvailability.FullName = details[0].FullName;
  soccerAvailability.Email = emailTextVal;
```

Comment: Your linq query is mapping to List<PlayerDetails> but in the query you are doing Select(p => new { p.FullName }). So in other words creating a new anonymous type at that point. So hence the type mapping failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just select the entire `PlayerDetail` record?

```
List <PlayerDetails> details = conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(x => x.Email == emailTextVal).ToList();
SoccerAvailability soccerAvailability = new SoccerAvailability();
soccerAvailability.FullName = details[0].FullName;
soccerAvailability.Email = emailTextVal;
```

alternately, you really only need to select the `FullName`, since you already know the e-mail value

Answer (score 1):

You should not mix up Lambda with C# Expression, i mean you can, but i wouldn't recommend it. 
I think this is the query you need:

```
(from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>()
where x.Email == emailTextVal
select new {
  Name = x.FullName,
  Email = x.Email
}).ToList()
```